# What does this line mean in my cronjob tab?

Tags: centos, cron

*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php somephpfile.php>> /dev/null 2>&1

What exactly does the dev/null 2 mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's redirecting STDER (Standard Error) to go along with STDOUT (Standard Out). In short, both of them are redirected to /dev/null, meaning no output from the program is ever displayed.

Comment: So that you don't get an email if the command output something :)

Answer (score 6):

`2>&1` means "send stderr to stdout."

`>>/dev/null` means "append stdout to /dev/null," which is a way of hiding program output by sending it into `/dev/null`, whose only purpose in life is to act like a black hole for data. (Strictly speaking, for `/dev/null`, `>>/dev/null` is the same as `>/dev/null`.)

These rules are evaluated from right to left, so in combination they say, "hide everything output to stderr and stdout." A common mistake is to specify them in the reverse order, which will not hide the stderr output.

Also worth knowing: you can explicitly send both streams to `/dev/null` by saying `1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null` *or* `&>/dev/null` rather than sending stderr to stdout and then sending stdout to `/dev/null`.

Comment: this was the best answer as it was explained the best. However I had already picked an answer :S

Answer (score 1):

It means redirect standard error and standard output to nothing (throw it away).